# Python cx-Freeze app works on Intel mac, not on M1

Tags: python, apple-m1, cx-freeze

I'm making a game in python and trying to freeze it with cx-freeze on my M1 Mac. The problem doesn't occur on my Intel mac.

The when I try to run the executable in the .app file, it just says "zsh: Killed", or in bash, "Killed: 9".

My python version is 3.10.6 and my Mac is version 12.3

This is the setup.py file, run using `python3 setup.py bdist_mac`:

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles = [
(A bunch of tuples with paths)
]
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
build_options = {'packages': ['pygame', 'random', 'sys'], 'include_files': includefiles}
mac_options = {'include_resources': includefiles}

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

append_script_to_exe = False

executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base, target_name = 'FORG')
]

setup(name='FORG',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = {'build_exe': build_options, 'bdist_mac': mac_options},
      executables = executables)
```

The error I get when looking in Console:

```
{"app_name":"FORG","timestamp":"2022-08-13 10:22:13.00
-0400","app_version":"","slice_uuid":"52504613-66f6-3a81-b20e-b3ab780f02f7","build_version":"","platform":0,"bundleID":"FORG-1.0","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.3 (21E230)","incident_id":"0D27155E-BB02-488A-9675-22B058AE22C1","name":"FORG"}
{
  "uptime" : 110000,
  "procLaunch" : "2022-08-13 10:22:08.9899 -0400",
  "procRole" : "Background",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro18,3",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 2784824485627,
  "coalitionID" : 14898,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.3",
    "build" : "21E230",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-08-13 10:22:09.6456 -0400",
  "incident" : "0D27155E-BB02-488A-9675-22B058AE22C1",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 34599,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 2784840206408,
  "translated" : false,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "procName" : "FORG",
  "procPath" : "\/Users\/USER\/Documents\/*\/FORG-1.0.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/FORG",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleIdentifier":"FORG-1.0"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"8591299B-4DE9-5B17-8FD3-895DD9D58551","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "FORG-1.0",
  "crashReporterKey" : "5E647B9D-5174-4F00-B354-62DD880A485E",
  "wakeTime" : 2071,
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "2C8EBC5E-30D1-4C55-B9E5-9D285AA0668B",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "vmRegionInfo" : "0x100658000 is in 0x100658000-0x10065c000;  bytes after start: 0  bytes before end: 16383\n      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      UNUSED SPACE AT START\n--->  mapped file                 100658000-10065c000    [   16K] r-x\/r-x SM=COW  ...t_id=2ff78be1\n      mapped file                 10065c000-100660000    [   16K] rw-\/rw- SM=COW  ...t_id=2ff78be1",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000032, 0x0000000100658000","rawCodes":[50,4301619200],"type":"EXC_BAD_ACCESS","signal":"SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid)","subtype":"UNKNOWN_0x32 at 0x0000000100658000"},
  "termination" : {"namespace":"CODESIGNING","flags":0,"code":2},
  "vmregioninfo" : "0x100658000 is in 0x100658000-0x10065c000;  bytes after start: 0  bytes before end: 16383\n      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      UNUSED SPACE AT START\n--->  mapped file                 100658000-10065c000    [   16K] r-x\/r-x SM=COW  ...t_id=2ff78be1\n      mapped file                 10065c000-100660000    [   16K] rw-\/rw- SM=COW  ...t_id=2ff78be1",
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":2104,"task_for_pid":95},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
],
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadHighlighted" : 0
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000008
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "61301e3a61217b3110231469",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_FIND_MY_CONFIGURATION_FILES" : "6216ae152a40e71046e16225"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000016
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
},
  "reportNotes" : [
  "_dyld_process_info_create failed with 6",
  "dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed",
  "Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\\_(ツ)_\/¯",
  "thread_get_state(PAGEIN) returned 0x10000003: (ipc\/send) invalid destination port",
  "thread_get_state(EXCEPTION) returned 0x10000003: (ipc\/send) invalid destination port",
  "thread_get_state(FLAVOR) returned 0x10000003: (ipc\/send) invalid destination port"
]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve the issue ?

Comment: No. I've just forgotten about it and moved on to other things.